# BASH : How to create optimal loop which extract archive, enter to the directory extracted and execute command inside?

Tags: linux, bash, npm

I search an optimal loop to extract all archives in their directory, enter in each directory and execute script. But my script is not working :

```
#!/bin/bash
    for file in ./$file.tar.gz;
        do
            tar -xvf "$file"
            cd "${file%.tar.gz}" || exit
            npm install
            npm link
        done
    echo "it's ok"
```

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Comment: Excuse me, i wasn't clear, my script doesn't working

Comment: _"not working"_ is not a more **specific** question than before

Comment: I'm looking for a more optimal way to extract archives and execute code inside the extracted folder. I think my loop is not good.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is this about optimization, or about a real problem?

Comment: How do you define "optimal loop"? What **exactly** is not working with the given script?

Comment: Where do you **extract** anything in your code?

Comment: In your loop, you assume that the variable `file` is already defined in your environment (since you are using `./$file.tar.gz`) but then you also use `file` as the control variable for the loop. Before you thrieve for creating an _optimal_ loop, write a sub-optimal one which is at least working somehow!

Comment: You need to go back to the default level.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will resume my script

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forget to change back to the base directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
base_dir="$PWD"
for file in *.tar.gz; do
  cd -- "${base_dir}"
  tar xvf "$file"
  cd -- "${file%.tar.gz}" || continue
  npm install
  npm link
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction as well as the explanation